# Template HTML is always cached in browser

Tags: apache2, angular

I've got a fairly simple Angular2 application in the works, and I'm trying to demo it to my boss on our staging server (typical Ubuntu LAMP). Every time I update a template and redeploy, I also have to clear my browser cache -- and so does my boss, and so do my future users! Not good!

I'm using `templateUrl` to load in my components' templates, and they are always being cached by the browser. I've tried disabling caching in `.htaccess` but it only seems to set the headers on the initial request and not for any of the XHR.

Is there a way to configure apache to disable caching for XHR? Or just completely disable browser caching no matter what?

Or am I doing something wrong in Angular? Is it a bad idea to run an Angular app on Apache?

Any advice or ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll find that it's Angular caching the templates in the browser so nothing to do with Apache.

Comment: If you have to clear browser cache, then yes, it is Apache's fault, it should be configured properly.

Comment: Probably http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html to configure the timespan how long the browser should keep the received files in cache before fetching them again (don't know Apache well, just googled and posted the first result ;-) )

Comment: @Brad I'm pretty sure it is not Angular caching the templates. My understanding is that the template cache will clear every page reload.

Comment: @estus and Gunter -- I'll take another swing at my apache configuration. I've tried mod_expires and setting headers with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Apache doing the caching, but the problem was simply a misunderstanding on my part. I never cleared my cache once I set Apache to stop caching. I assumed it would happen automatically, which is obviously not the way browser caching works.

So I'll have to clear my boss's cache one last time, and from there on out the problem will be solved.